# How to remove Users from Permission Set when uninstalling Managed Package

Tags: apex, managed-package, permission-sets

I've like to automate the process of removing users from a `Permission Set` when uninstalling a managed package:

```
global class AppUninstallHandler implements UninstallHandler {

    global void onUninstall(UninstallContext ctx) {

        List<String> names = new List<String> {'Power_User', 'Normal_User'};

        Set<Id> ids = (new Map<Id, PermissionSet>([SELECT ID FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name IN : names])).keySet();

        List<PermissionSetAssignment> assigments = [SELECT ID FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE PermissionSetId IN :ids];

        delete assigments;
    }
}
```

But I still get the error message asking me to manually remove them before I can uninstall.

I am guessing the `UninstallHandler` cannot run unit after I've removed the users already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. The uninstall handler won't run until the uninstall is successful. You could create a page/component/whatever to automate the removal of the permission sets, you just can't use this specific interface to do so.